# pagination design in cakephp

Tags: css, cakephp, pagination

This is the [Pagination](http://jsfiddle.net/P6UR8/) style I want. And this is the [Pagination](http://jsfiddle.net/xy6gg/) style I get. Can anyone tell me how I can get it done?

```
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->first('&lsaquo;', array('tag' => 'a', 'title' => __('First page'), 'escape' => false));
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('&laquo;', array('tag' => 'a',  'title' => __('Previous page'), 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'a', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'navlinks'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => false, 'tag' => 'a', 'currentTag' => 'span', 'currentClass' => 'navlinks current'));
    echo $this->Paginator->next('&raquo;', array('tag' => 'a', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'title' => __('Next page'), 'escape' => false), null, array('tag' => 'a', 'disabledTag' => 'span', 'escape' => false, 'class' => 'navlinks'));
    echo $this->Paginator->last('&rsaquo;', array('tag' => 'a', 'title' => __('First page'), 'escape' => false));
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tag` attribute is used to define the *wrapping* tag you want to use and you can't put an anchor inside another. Set it to false if you don't want to wrap your links. Unfortunately you can't specify a class for the link, only for the wrapper so you'll have to adjust your styles.